# Answer to closed question is no longer relevant

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions, rollbacks

When I answered [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31392422), the title was "Append an xml file to another xml file C#". I answered the question, but the question was later closed as a duplicate.

However, it appears the asker is still expecting answers to his problem. The person changed the title to "Append one XML file to another using LINQ to XML" and added more detail in the body (again, after the question was closed), and because of this, my answer is no longer relevant.

Should the edits they made after it was closed be rolled back? Or should it just be ignored because it's already been closed?

I didn't want to edit my answer because not only did my answer answer his original question, but also there were good answers for the question it was a duplicate of. Should I bother editing my answer to fit this new question? I suggested that he ask a new question instead, but I'm not sure if he did so.

Comment: Roll it back, tell him to go ask a new question.  If he rolls back the original, flag.

Comment: Looking at their edits, and the comments on your answer, to me it really looks more like they're clarifying their question, which in turn could help make it different from the duplicate target. (I didn't look at the target here, so I don't know if it succeeded or not.) They're still wanting to combine two xml files. The title is the only _real_ change that invalidates your answer, and that should therefore be changed back. But otherwise, the edits look fine to me, as they added more detail and their attempted code. (This is just my opinion of course.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think when a question is closed as a duplicate unless it is wrong, it should be left alone. Wrong means that what was really intended is not a duplicate even if without the edit it wasn't clear. But something beyond a clarification should not happen. This includes major code changes to avoid being a duplicate, language changes etc... In my opinion that is why you can't add another answer to a duplicate.

I think it is wrong to have changed the post in the first place since the request was for a different language even if it will make it a non-duplicate. It would be better for him to make a new question as Will suggested.

I also looked at your answer and it seems pretty accurate. I wouldn't change it.

Comment: It seems that will has rolled back the edit, so the problem has been resolved.